# Transform all list arguments of all functions?

Tags: python, list, typechecking

When only providing a single element, it's easy to forget to put it in a list!

```py
def listify(supposed_lst:object=None):
    """
    - When only providing a single element, it's easy to forget to put it in a list!
    - If touching every list arg, then might as well validate it!
    """
    if (supposed_lst is not None):
        if (not isinstance(supposed_lst, list)):
            supposed_lst = [supposed_lst]
        # If it was already a list, check it for emptiness and `None`.
        elif (isinstance(supposed_lst, list)):
            if (not supposed_lst):
                raise ValueError(dedent(
                    f"Yikes - The list you provided contained `None` as an element." \
                    f"{supposed_lst}"
                ))
            if (None in supposed_lst):
                raise ValueError(dedent(
                    f"Yikes - The list you provided contained `None` as an element." \
                    f"{supposed_lst}"
                ))
    return supposed_lst
```

Before I go about `listify`'ing every potential list object in 5,000 lines worth of functions in my API like so...

```py
supposed_lst = listify(supposed_lst)
```

...is there a better way (less code) to perform this?  Let's say I have 100 list arguments. That's 100 `listfify`'s.

I am type-checking all `:list` arguments, so strict type checking would be an acceptable solution too.

Comment: What do you mean by "better"? Performance wise?

Comment: less code. let's say i have 350 list arguments. that's 350 listfies. will edit

Comment: Under what circumstances do you really need such a function? Also, why does `None` not get wrapped in a list like any other non-list argument?

Comment: Because `None` is needed to trigger null conditions. My main user is researcher. They aren't great programmers. the single element list thing is a hangup i have observed.

Comment: I guess you either _listify_ before every call, or you make the functions that take lists _listify_ their argument before using if. For the latter you might want to check out "python decorators", they let you manipulate functions in a fancy way.

Comment: `elif (isinstance(suppsed_list, list))` should just be `else:`

Comment: And you don't even need `else:` if it's just going to `pass`.

Comment: There might be a way to do this using a decorator, but I think it will actually be more complicated than just doing all the `param = listify(param)` calls.

Comment: This is kinda tricky since you don't declare types in python. By visual inspection alone it's impossible to figure out if a function parameter is supposed to be a list or not so there's no simple way of doing this if you have hundreds of functions to check. My current line of thinking is to check for the function parameters being used in the code body of the function and see if they ever get invoked using square brackets. This would identify them as being lists and you can add the listify func for them at the top of the function code.

Comment: @Barmar the extra elifs are just to express my intent. they aren't in my real coder.

Comment: actually, i decided to check lists for emptiness and containing `None`'s  while inside listify... ended up reducing lines when applied to the codebase.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the simple version I coded up. It's pretty fragile, but the idea is there and you can add whatever signatures and safety checks you need. Right now I'm just looking for a signature of "params[" to determine if a parameter is a list or not. This will probably catch most of them without too many false positives.

## file to be changed

```py
import whatever
import nonesense

def noListHere(a, b, c):
    a += 1;
    b -= 1;
    c = a + b / c;
    return a + b + c;

blah = woop;
beep = blah;

def oneList(az, bz, cz):
    az = None;
    bz += cz[0];
    b = [0,0]; # red herring
    b[0] += 1;
    for d in range(bz):
        bz += 1;

fwoop = noListHere(1, 2,3);

def twoList(a, b, c):
    a += 1;
    b[0] += 2;
    c[0] = a;
```

## metaprogramming

```py
# count number of tabs or whitespace
# there's almost certainly a better way
def countSpace(line):
    counter = 0;
    while len(line) > 0 and (line[0] == ' ' or line[0] == '\t'):
        line = line[1:];
        counter += 1;
    return counter;

# load target file as text
file = open("target.py", "r");
lines = [];
for line in file:
    # print(line[:-1]);
    lines.append(line[:-1]); # drop the endline character
file.close();

# section them off into code bodies
func = []; # [line index, parameters, code body, indent];

# hunt for "def"
for index in range(len(lines)):
    line = lines[index];
    indent = line.find("def");
    if indent != -1:
        # try to pull out parameter names
        left = line.find("(");
        right = line.find(")");
        sub = line[left+1:right];
        sub = sub.replace(' ', '');
        params = sub.split(',');

        # find the end of the indentation
        func_index = index;
        index += 1;
        body = [];
        spacing = 0;
        while index < len(lines):
            # check spacing
            line = lines[index];
            index += 1;
            spacing = countSpace(line);
            if spacing <= indent:
                break;

            # add to body
            body.append(line);

        # add to list
        func.append([func_index, params, body, indent]);
        print("Func Index: " + str(func_index));

# reverse list
func = func[::-1];

# figure out which parameters are used as lists
for f in func:
    # unpack
    index, params, body, indent = f;

    # scroll through body lines looking for this signature:
    # param[
    # add more signatures or more specific requirements as necessary
    list_list = [];
    for param in params:
        flag = False;
        for line in body:
            if line.find(param + "[") != -1:
                flag = True;
                break;
        list_list.append(flag);

    # for each list variable, meta in the listify thing
    for a in range(len(params)):
        if list_list[a]:
            prefix = '\t';
            lines.insert(index + 1, (prefix * (indent + 1)) + "listify(" + params[a] + ");");

# rebuild file
file = open("output.py", "w");
for line in lines:
    file.write(line + "\n");
file.close();
```

## target file after metaprogramming

```py
import whatever
import nonesense

def noListHere(a, b, c):
    a += 1;
    b -= 1;
    c = a + b / c;
    return a + b + c;

blah = woop;
beep = blah;

def oneList(az, bz, cz):
    listify(cz);
    az = None;
    bz += cz[0];
    b = [0,0]; # red herring
    b[0] += 1;
    for d in range(bz):
        bz += 1;

fwoop = noListHere(1, 2,3);

def twoList(a, b, c):
    listify(c);
    listify(b);
    a += 1;
    b[0] += 2;
    c[0] = a;
```

Comment: Thank you. So this parses each function in the file and generates a new file that includes the listify lines. +1 for creativity

Comment: yep. oh right, it should be param = listify(param), sorry.